# Frequent HTTP connection closures in HTTP client

Tags: go, http, kubernetes, tcp

I have set up a golang application which receives a high amount of traffic (100 req/s), and size of the JSON payload in each request varies but can reach up to 100KB. I have been noticing intermittent errors which occur in about 1/5000 requests, when decoding the http request body in the client.

The service is deployed in kubernetes and receives traffic from another service in the same cluster. To replicate this issue "locally" I have exposed the service over an ingress and am able to call it remotely by using a load-testing tool (vegeta) to spam requests at production traffic request levels, and note the same errors which occur in production. When I run the app locally on my laptop and send requests at the same rate as I do to the containerized version, it doesn't throw any errors, which makes me think that the issue has to do with the environment in which the service is deployed.

Another interesting point to note is that the greater the rate of incoming requests, or the larger the average JSON payload which is sent to the service, the greater the proportion of errors, or closed connections.

The service is written in golang, and the handler looks like this:

```
func handleEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    req := new(reqObject)

    defer r.Body.Close()

    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&req)

    if err != nil {
           // handle error...
       return
    }
}
```

The error which is caught and thrown in the error handler block, is: `read tcp ip:port->ip:port: i/o timeout`. Though from debugging and profiling, I can see that the error occurs during the `http.(*connReader).Read` stage, which throws an error as we are trying to read from a broken connection (profile image attached which notes this).

My hunch is that there is some sort of bottleneck in my kubernetes deployment which is throttling high traffic throughput, as under the same conditions, the local deployment encounters no problems.

The CPU usage for the pod sits at around 2% during high throughput load, and I haven't picked up on any memory leaks when profiling

Thanks in advance!

[Profile which indicates point of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRuzc.png)